# Removing encoded text from strings read from txt file

Tags: python, html, encoding, utf-8, decoding

Here's the problem:

I copied and pasted this entire list to a txt file from https://www.cboe.org/mdx/mdi/mdiproducts.aspx

Sample of text lines:

`BFLY - The CBOE S&P 500 Iron Butterfly Index
BPVIX - CBOE/CME FX British Pound Volatility Index 
BPVIX1 - CBOE/CME FX British Pound Volatility First Term Structure Index
BPVIX2 - CBOE/CME FX British Pound Volatility Second Term Structure Index`

These lines of course appear normal in my text file, and I saved the file with utf-8 encoding.

My goal is to use python to strip out only the symbols from this long list, .e.g. BFLY, VPVIX etc, and write them to a new file

I am using the following code to read the file and split it:

```
x=open('sometextfile.txt','r')
y=x.read().split()
```

The issue I'm seeing is that there are unfamiliar characters popping up and they are affecting my ability to filter the list. Example:

```
print(y[0])
ï»¿BFLY
```

I'm guessing that these characters have something to do with the encoding and I have tried a few different things with the codec module without success. Using .decode('utf-8') throws an error when trying to use it against the above variables x or y. I am able to use .encode('utf-8'), which obviously makes things even worse.

The main problem is that when I try to loop through the list and remove any items that are not all upper case or contain non-alpha characters. Ex:

```
y[0].isalpha()
False
y[0].isupper()
False
```

So in this example the symbol BFLY ends up being removed from the list.

Funny thing is that these characters are not present in a txt file if I do something like:

```
q=open('someotherfile.txt','w')
q.write(y[0])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would really like to understand why this frequently happens when copying and pasting text from web pages like this one.

Comment: Can you edit your question where you show data file info -- use {} button to maintain line formatting.  I'd do it, but it is too short an edit to be allowed

Comment: I copied as well and pasted into a file using vim.  Perhaps your text editor is set up to save files in something other than utf-8? or perhaps it is changing quotes to curly quotes

Comment: I am using windows notepad unfortunately. If I copy the same to text to notepad++ I don't see anything that would indicate the existence of these characters. Maybe I'll try saving it with notepad++ instead.

Comment: Sorry guys, this does look to be an oddity associated with txt files saved in windows notepad. I should have known better. The same copy paste into notepad++ and saved as .txt did not have this issue. I guess you can't make an egg without breaking a few omelets.

Comment: You should look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Notepad There is a reference to unicode bug.  Are you on older windows system?

Comment: Thanks, reading it now. I'm on win7. I'll probably just opt to never use MS anything again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Regex?

I think this will catch the letters in caps

```
"[A-Z]{1,}/?[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]?"
```

This is better. I got a list of all such symbols. Here's my result.

```
['BFLY', 'CBOE', 'BPVIX', 'CBOE/CME', 'FX', 'BPVIX1', 'CBOE/CME', 'FX', 'BPVIX2', 'CBOE/CME', 'FX']
```

Here's the code

```
import re
reg_obj = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{1,}/?[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]?')
sym = reg_obj.findall(a)enter code here
print(sym)
```

Comment: That pretty much does the trick, however I also need to filter out any that are not alpha characters, like CBOE/CME. I was just using a for loop to do it, but this appears to be a more efficient way. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give sample. Everything I did now I learned today. You you could. You just need to escape characters and that's all. Give samples and we'll figure it out

Comment: So in the above lines:

BFLY - The CBOE S&P 500 Iron Butterfly Index
BPVIX - CBOE/CME FX British Pound Volatility Index 
BPVIX1 - CBOE/CME FX British Pound Volatility First Term Structure Index
BPVIX2 - CBOE/CME FX British Pound Volatility Second Term Structure Index 
BPVIX3 - CBOE/CME FX British Pound Volatility Third Term Structure Index

The only items I want in the list are:
BFLY
BPVIX
BPVIX1
BPVIX2

It will probably be a little more tricky to make sure the symbols that contain numbers are left in the list.

Comment: If it's as simple as I think then you just need to index the first element. Just do sym[0] and that's it. Except I'm not getting you right.